# AFNetworking - saving a downloaded file

Tags: objective-c, ios, download, afnetworking

I am using AFNetworking and can successfully download a file.

At the end of the download, it does not appear in the directory that I set it to be though.

I did some searching and came across a few questions here on SO where it is suggested I use:

```
[_operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
```

But that comes up with an error and it is as far as I can tell not mentioned in their documentation.

the error is :

> /Users/Jeff/Documents/Dropbox-01/Dropbox/Xcode Projects/Try Outs - JEFF/testDownload/testDownload/JWKDownloadViewController.m:177:10: No visible @interface for 'AFURLConnectionOperation' declares the selector 'setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:failure:'

**Is there an updated line I need to use???**

Comment: Make sure you save the file when its fully downloaded

Comment: That is what this line is for right? _operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:_streamingURL append:NO];

Comment: @Dhara here file gets download byte by byte.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes make sure that u have used correct path into `NSOutputStream`

Add this:

```
[_operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
NSLog(@"Successfully downloaded file");
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
  NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
[_operation start];
```

Comment: Yup I had to check the output - I was saving the path, but then forgot to add the file name to it:-)

Answer (score 8):

```
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"..."]];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request] autorelease];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"filename"];
operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:path append:NO];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Successfully downloaded file to %@", path);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];

[operation start];
```

Comment: how to pass parameter in it?